# How to pass user to docker entrypoint running as root

Tags: docker

I need to run a script as root while booting my container.
After digging a bit I found that the solution is to create an entrypoint that ends with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

// run your script as root
echo "FOO=BAR" > /etc/my-config

su - my-user
$@
```

Now this will work fine to run things as `my-user`
But what if I want to run something as different user eg. `root`?

In other words lets say I do:

```
docker exec -it --user=root abcd1234567890 /bin/bash
```

Where can I find the value of `--user=` so I will be able to correctly change `su - my-user` to `su - root`?